# Makefile ifeq Inside Target Always Going into else

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to generate a Makefile rule which will have separate C flags depending on if the c file is in a child of the `Core` directory.  I have the following rule inside my Makefile:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
ifeq ($(strip $(firstword $(findstring Core,$(dir $<)))),Core)
    $(info Hit if...)
    $(CC) -c $(C_CORE_FLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@
else
    $(info $(dir $<))
    $(info $(strip $(firstword $(findstring Core,$(dir $<)))))
    $(info Hit else...)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@
endif
```

The `ifeq` statement isn't working at all though, and always goes into the `else` block, even when the `$(info $(strip $(firstword $(findstring Core,$(dir $<)))))` line prints out `Core`.

Here is the output from the `Core/src/main.c` target:

```
Core/Src/
Core
Hit else...
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -I. -ICore/Inc -Og -Wall -Werror -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -g -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -MF"build/main.d" -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=build/main.lst Core/Src/main.c -o build/main.o
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do here?  I tried using bash `if` statements instead of the Makefile `ifeq` statement, but then none of the output echoed to the terminal.

I'm using make version 4.3-4.1build1 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on WSL 2.

Comment: You can't use ifeq etc. inside recipes.  They are parsed and take effect when the makefile is read in, which is a long time before the recipe is invoked.  When the makefile is read in, automatic variables like `$<` are always empty (because they depend on which rule is being invoked) which is why you get the behavior you see.  You'll have to use the shell's conditional operations, inside the recipe, not make's conditional operations.

Comment: Basically: you have to use ALL shell operations.  Don't use `ifeq`, use the shell's `if`.  Don't use make's `$(info...)` function, use the shell's `echo` or `printf`.

Comment: It's generally not considered a good idea to add conditional statements into recipes like this.  You can just define a different pattern rule like `$(BUILD_DIR)/Core/%.o: Core/%.c Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)` that uses the different flags, and that pattern rule will be used instead because it's more specific.  Or, you can use a target pattern rule to add an extra variable setting to the targets for `Core` sources.  Without seeing more of your makefile we can't give exact suggestions, but using an if-statement in a recipe like this is very unusual and non-make-like.

Comment: I agree that this isn't very make-like and I like your idea of adding a Core/%.c rule.  The issue for me is that I have multiple subdirectories inside of Core that all have c files that need this recipe applied.  Is there a ** similar wildcard in make that will match any subdirectory at any level?

Comment: I don't think I understand.  If the pattern rule you have above matches all the files in the subdirectories, then the Core pattern will also match.  But to answer your question, no, there is no such wildcard for pattern rules.

Comment: I guess it's mainly an issue with project folder setup.  I have files in Core/Src, Core/Src/tasks, Core/Src/drivers, etc.  A Core/Src/%.c rule doesn't run for the files in Core/Src/tasks or other subdirectories.  There is a vpath rule for the %.c files: `vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(C_SOURCES)))`, so maybe I could try to get a separate vpath rule for anything in Cores.  I'm not super familiar with that though.

Comment: But, I didn't say `Core/Src/%.c`.  I said `Core/%.c`.  That will match any file in any directory under `Core`.

Comment: Interesting.  Core/%.c isn't hitting any of my files and they're all falling back to the %.c recipe.  It seems to only be matching files in the Core directory, not any subdirectories

Comment: You answered my original question though, so thank you.  I was doing illegal things in the Make world.  I'll try to fix this and may open up another question if I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I just created a quick test with `./foo.c`, `./Core/bar.c`, and `./Core/Src/baz.c`, then a Makefile with `all: obj/foo.o obj/Core/bar.o obj/Core/Src/baz.o` and two rules: `obj/%.o : %.c ; @echo basic $@ from $<` and also `obj/Core/%.o : Core/%.c ; @echo core $@ from $<` and it worked exactly as expected: the _basic_ rule was used to build `obj/foo.o` and the _core_ rule was used to build `obj/Core/bar.o` and `obj/Core/Src/baz.o`.  So, if it's not working for you you'll have to provide a small, self-contained example of how it's failing.

Comment: Sure, I made up an example project.  Any idea what the best way is to send that?  I think the issue is how all of my compiled files are placed in the `build/` directory and not into subfolders within that.  Due to that, `vpath` is used to include all the folders that contain .c files.  This project is for an STM32 microcontroller, and unfortunately, it would be a pretty large overhaul to change from ST's default project structure.

Comment: Here's a link to my example project: https://github.com/cvanbeek13/Makefile-Subdirectory-Wildcards/tree/main

Comment: We expect example code to be presented *in the question*, not at an external site.  This is essential for the question and any answers to be useful to people other than you.

Comment: Yes, if you use VPATH you can't use this solution at all.  This wasn't clear in your question.  You'll have to do something very different because you can't differentiate the targets that came from files under Core vs. targets that came from anywhere else.  You could use target-specific variable assignment, like `$(patsubst %.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(filter Core/%.c,$(SOURCES)))): EXTRA_CFLAGS = <flags-for-Core-sources>` then add `$(EXTRA_CFLAGS)` to your compile line, or something like that.

Comment: Dang, that worked like a charm!  Thank you so much for all your help with this!